# Mac OS x gives ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, 64-bit

I am trying to compile a c++ program which works fine in Xcode but gives error in terminal.

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Example* example =new Example();
    example->show();
}
```

example.h

```
class Example {
public:

    void show();
};
```

example.cpp

```
void Example::show() {

    std::cout<<"Hello World"<<std::endl;
}
```

Error i get

```
 "Example::show()", referenced from:
      _main in cckpIa3V.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am compiling using g++

```
g++ -o test main.cpp
```

Comment: What does "but gives error in terminal" actually mean?  Do you mean when attempting to compile on the command line?  If so, show your command line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't linking in `example.o`.  You don't show your command line/Makefile, so this is (roughly) what you need to type:

```
$ g++ -o example main.cpp example.cpp
```

That will compile and link the source files to an executable called `example`.

Comment: How to compile if i have a lot of class files in different directories

Comment: Create a Makefile is the most reliable way, then you can simply type `make all` or some such.  But basically you can just reference the source files like this: `$ g++ -o example src/file1.cpp ../othersrc/file2.cpp /tmp/file3.cpp`